# How to type hint a method that returns a subclass?

Tags: python, oop, python-typing

I have the setup

```py
import typing

class A:
    def get_b(self) -> B: # <- ERROR: B is not defined yet
       return b # <- and instance of B here

class B(A): # <- subclass of A, defined after A is defined
    pass
```

Is there a clean way to type hint the method `get_b`?

**Edit**: thanks to the wonderful answers, this problem is not really addressed in the documentation, but in some [PEPs](https://peps.python.org/), one of them is [the problem of forward declarations](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#the-problem-of-forward-declarations)

Comment: Either enclose `B` in string quotes, or put `from __future__ import annotations` at the top of the file.

Comment: Aaah, the `from __future__ import annotations` is gold. Thanks! Care to add this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put `B` in quotes like:

```py
class A:
    def get_b(self) -> 'B':
       return b

class B(A):
    pass
```

Comment: Thank you!! It would be great if you could add a link to the documentation...

Comment: Sure, you can find it here: https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#forward-references.